# Error coming on accessing plate of jpn why?

Tags: java

Here in my code it is giving error in move method of Ball class in if(collision()) as it is unable to resolve plate ,the collision method of Ball class is unable to resolve plate object i.e jpn.plate is giving error  but when I saw this code on internet it was working fine, why?

JPanel.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JPanel extends JPanel {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    Ball ball = new Ball(this);
    Plate plate = new Plate(this);

    void move() {// move
        ball.move();
        plate.move();
    }

    JPanel(){
        //constructor
        KeyListener k=new KeyListener(){

            @Override

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //System.out.println(KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

                plate.keyPressed(e);
                @Override

            }
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                plate.keyReleased(e);                                          }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };
        addKeyListener(k);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {// paint

        super.paint(g);// pehle screen saaf karo pehle jaisi
        setBackground(Color.black);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ball.paint(g2d);
        plate.paint(g2d);
        // super.paint(g);//agar yaha to puri screen pehle jaisi saaf ho jaegi
    }

    public void gameOver() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "GameOver", "GameOver",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        System.exit(ABORT);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {// main

        Jpanel jp = new Jpanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chota Bheem");
        frame.add(jp);
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (true) {
            jp.move();
            jp.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Ball.java

```
class Ball {

    int x = 0;
    int xs = -1, ys = -1;
    int y = 0;

    static final int DIAMETER = 30;
    JPanel jpn;

    Ball(JPanel jpn) {
        this.jpn = jpn;
    }

    public void move() {

        if (x + xs < 0) {
            xs = 1;
        } else if (y + ys < 0) {
            ys = 1;
        } else if (x + xs > jpn.getWidth() - 30) {
            xs = -1;
        } else if (y + ys > jpn.getHeight() - 30) {
            ys = -1;
        }
        x = x + xs;
        y = y + ys;
        if (collision()) {
            ys = -1;
            y = jpn.plate.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
        }
        if (y + ys > 490) {
            ((Jpanel) jpn).gameOver();
        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {

        return new Rectangle(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
    }

    public boolean collision() {
        return jpn.plate.getBounds().intersects(getBounds());
    }
}
```

Plate.java

```
class Plate {
    int x = 0;
    int xa = 0;
    Jpanel j;
    static final int Y = 490;
    static final int WIDTH = 60;
    static final int HEIGHT = 10;

    Plate(Jpanel j) {
        this.j = j;
    }

    public void move() {
        if (x + xa > 0 && x + xa < j.getWidth() - 60) {
            x = x + xa;
        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        g.fillRect(x, 450, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            xa = -1;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            xa = 1;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        xa = 0;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public int getTop() {
        return Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: "when I saw this code on internet it was working fine" - then compare your code to what you found on Internet and find out what the difference is.

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: This is probably the worst-formatted code I've seen here so far. If you really want help could you at least put some effort into making your code readable?

Answer (score 0):

In you class `Ball`, `Jpanel` object `jpn` never had an attribute plate and java's `JPanel` doesn't have a plate attribute. So, you are getting the error.

I renamed the class named `JPanel` which extended `JPanel` to `JalPan` as it was causing a [circular reference error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference).

**EDIT**:

Here are your 3 classes:

1. Jalpan.java - http://pastebin.com/vcmtr4jm
2. Ball.java - http://pastebin.com/xH67dPWp
3. Plate.java - http://pastebin.com/EuaBEBhV

Comment: This was given on website edu4java.com even I was unable to understand why it was accessing plate through Jpanel thats why I posted it, please correct it.

Comment: @SuZure - Download the files and then run it. Nobody will correct/rectify your code for you. If u don't know something specific, as in how to do, we can help. But you ask me to do what u want to do, please call my office, place an order, pay the advance and take your software. Thanks!